# Assigning value to pointer throws exception

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I am new to C/C++, I'm trying to learn it, I have created the following function but it throws an exception, when I'm trying to assign the uppercase value to *string: Unhandled exception at 0x00411820 in CPP1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00417754.

```
void ToUpper(char* string)
{
    while(*string != '\0')
    {
        if(*string >= 97 && *string <= 122)
        {
            int symbol = *string;
            *string = symbol - 32;
        }
        string++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
char* x = "text"; 
ToUpper(x);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Let me guess, you're passing a string literal. Show us the `main` function.

Comment: Please show usage of this function

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to to the following thing: char* x = "text"; ToUpper(x);

Comment: Allocate the memory explicitly.

Comment: int and char are not convertible in C++ , so if you are using c++ this might be the problem and in C it could be passing string literal

Comment: After edit : it's the problem of string literal you can't edit that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
char* x = "text";
```

to

```
char x[] = "text";
```

DONE

Comment: Great, it works, but could you please explain why x[] works and char* [] doesn't, or point me to some resource where I can find it?

Comment: read this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: String literal resides in read only location and cannot be modified...

Answer (score 2):

Never *try* to change a const character string. Always use character arrays for this sort of manipulation.

Comment: It's rather "never _try_ to change..." ;)

Comment: Or `malloc`, `calloc`. If it is C++ even better, `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

Memory for "text" will be allocated in `.readonly` section.

```
char* x = "text";
```

Tyring to alter read-only section is undefined behaviour.

use `gcc -S filename.c` to view the assembly code. This gives you more idea about whereabouts of "text".

Like others suggested, I suggest to use `char x[] = "text"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
main()
{
    char *a = "text";
    char *x = malloc(strlen(a)+1); 
    strcpy(x,a);
    ToUpper(x);
    // ToUpper(a); // Fails
    printf("%s %s\n",a,x);
}
```

Output: `text TEXT`

ToUpper(a) fails, because the string is replaced in a protected memory area (in the middle of the code most likely, as at least 64-bit x86-processors have [rip] -relative addressing mode, which makes it lucrative to place data in between code lines...

Also `char x[]="text";` works, because now the complete array of x is placed in the stack. In case of `char *x = "text";` only the pointer is placed on stack, but the content points to restricted (read-only) memory.

Comment: Since the string length is known at compile-time, there is absolutely no point in using malloc. And if you do, call free().

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to try to modify a string literal by a pointer:

```
void f()
{
   char * p = "Naee";
   p[2] = 'm'; // error: assignment to const; result is undefined
}
```

Having string literals constant allows for significant optimizations in the storage allocation and access. If you want a string that you can modify
modify, you must copy the characters into an array:

```
void f()
{
   char p [] = "Eero"; 
   p [0] = 'Z'; // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this no need to create `symbol` varible

```
*string=*string-32;
```

but pass `array` to the function in calling environment rather passing `string literal`

so

```
char * str[] ="hello";
ToUpper(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to type cast the value in the assignment statement.

*string = *(char *)symbol - 32;

Comment: It doesn't solve anything, but it adds another major bug, causing the program to crash even harder.